# How to push a view controller without lag

Tags: ios, ios6

Whenever I push a view controller onto my navigation stack (on an iPhone 4) I can notice some very subtle lag between pressing the button and the controller actually starting to appear. Things run very smoothly when I run the app on the simulator.

I am creating my controller and doing all of the work associated with setting up the view on the main thread. There is no real intensive tasks that I can see, I am just allocating the view controller which then allocates it's view. The view is created programatically and consists of a number of UILabels and UITextfields, nothing fancy.

Is this type of UI work or the creation of the view controller not supposed to be done on the main thread? When I play around with some other apps on my phone they seem very snappy when navigating between screens.

Comment: Can you share the important code?

Comment: Can you share the code you used to push and also check whether you have some heavy looping or code in viewDidLoad and other view life cycle methods.

Comment: Simulator is still not a real device, it has more resources than the real device. And, yes, provide please some code. Maybe you are doing something before actual `pushViewController`? Or maybe, you are doing the allocating part in `viewWillAppear`?

Comment: This type of UI work _must_ be done of the main thread. As others have suggested, you should share what you're doing (e.g. synchronous network requests are a common culprit). Or run the app through the Instruments' "Time Profiler" and that can help you identify the culprit.